# Separating Structure with Ajax and MySql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I can think of plenty of ways to use ajax to load information from my database. For example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

However, I really want to separate my structure (HTML), behavior (JS/AJAX), style (CSS), and data (MySQL + PHP) to keep my website scalable.

The above example shows how to just paste in the HTML via AJAX into the existing HTML doc, but what if I have the HTML already and just want to modify HTML elements via ajax using one MySQL call?

**For example**

Say I have this structure (HTML)

```
<body>
    <h1 id="first">First name here</h1>
    <h2 id="last">Last name here</h2>
    <h3 id="email">Email here</h3>
</body>
```

I currently use PHP to make a MySQL query,

```
"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` = ".$id;
```

And of course I could assign each field to individual PHP vars, $first $last, $email. But then when it comes to using jQuery or plain ol AJAX, how do I use this single MySQL statement and single GET request from AJAX to change `<h1>`, `<h2>`, and `<h3>` in the above example?

I know I can use jQuery selectors

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#first').innerHTML = ?
    ...
)
```

But is there an elegant way to load values retrieved from PHP into jQ/js? (Let's assume I'm GETting the php doc via jQ/js).

Comment: Don't use w3fools, they teach you extremely bad programming habits. Besides that, pure MVC does not really fit for web apps.

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: For example, the very... example... you linked to opens up a ton of possibilities for SQL injection! Just send a GET request right to the page with this querystring: `?q='%20; DROP DATABASE something; --`. Ouch. Authentication? No problem, put it in through an `<iframe>`.

Comment: I don't understand how the title related to the question body. You want to know how to separate SERVER side M, V and C or just how to make a request from the client to the server?

Comment: I'm talking about MVC in a more fundamental way, I'm not actually using an MVC framework. Sorry, I know that's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way might be to use JSON with selectors, so return this from your PHP script:

```
{
    '#first': 'First name updated value',
    '#last': 'Last name updated value',
    '#email': 'etc.'
}
```

Then, when retrieving the results (don't forget to use `'json'` as your `dataType`):

```
for(var x in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        $(x).html(data[x]);
    }
}
```

Oh, and jQuery can do that for you too:

```
$.each(data, function(selector, newContent) {
    $(selector).html(newContent);
});
```

Comment: Wait, so the first snippet is JSON? That can be put in my PHP script?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz: Yup. PHP can be anything, not just HTML :) Even images.

Comment: I see, so one could just paste in the php vars there, like: '#first':$first, ?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz: Well, actually, you should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to do that - it will handle escaping and such.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP can return simple json, like the following:

```
[{ firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Smith", email: "joe@smith.com" }]
```

And in your ajax success callback, you can use [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) to render your html, or in other words, "fill your html with data."

What this looks like...

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="personContainer"></div>
</body>
<script id="personTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <h1>{{=firstName}}</h1>
  <h2>{{=lastName}}</2>
  <h3>{{=email}}</h3>
</script>
```

in Ajax success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    $("#personContainer").html(
      $("#personTmpl").render(data);
    ); // where data is in the json format above
  }
});
```

Similar example here: http://jsbin.com/ihuhep/3/edit